# how to install globally my node script and distribute

Tags: node.js

I did a node console script for some internal task using some dependences and it is working well. Now I have two questions:

**1) how to install it globally on my computer?**

I need to launch the script like this:

```
node myscript.js PARAM1
```

And, how I´ve said, it works ok. The fact is that now I want to "install" my script globally. How to do that? I´m mac user and I know that I can create an alias like this:

```
alias myexec='node myscript.js'
```

then I could use it like this:

```
myexec PARAM1
```

is this the correct way to do it? is there any other alternative maybe?

**2) How to distribute?**
I have some computers on my company where I need to install it (Windows & Mac), I can clone the repo and do the alias thing... is this my best option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://markmarkoh.com/nodejs-npm-and-executables/

Comment: oks, I´ll try it. Can you answer the question in order to close it?

Comment: Maybe you should write the answer yourself if @Quentin doesn't.